# iText: PDF size when adding an image

Tags: image, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using iText 5.5.4 for creating PDF from Java, and it's a great library.

This is not an issue or wrong behaviour. It's only a curious fact, that I'm trying to understand.

I have a three-page PDF, with header, footer, tables, etc.
Its size is 96KB.

I have added a 4th page with a 950KB JPEG image. It fits in an A4 page dimensions.
Adding 96KB + 950KB + 4th page metadata + others(header, footer) , I expected the new PDF was about 1.15MB

But the final size was 1.41MB

So, I have these two questions:

- Is there anything wrong in my estimate? Why does image addition imply such overload?
- If I scale the image to 75% with iText, the new resulting PDF also is 1.41MB of size. Does PDF include the original JPEG image, despite of the reduction?

I insist: the behaviour is right. It's only my own curiosity.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I don't have permission to share the image. My code to add an image to PDF is:

```
public Document addNewElement(Document input, String imageFilename) throws DocumentException {  

try {       
    input.newPage();

    Image image = Image.getInstance(path + imageFilename);

    input.add(image);           

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

return input;
```

}

Comment: Please share your pivotal code and the image file.

Comment: Ok, the code looks straight forward. Without your sample image, though, I can only test with images I have here, and with my sample JPEG I get less than 1.5 KB overhead; the JPEG is embedded as is, so the overhead even is nearly constant. Thus, there is something peculiar about your image. Without you sharing the image in question, you hardly will get help.

Answer (score 0):

**Scaling an image with iText doesn't reduce or increase the number of pixels of an image.** The size of the image inside of the PDF is independent of the scaling factor you use. The only thing that changes is the perceived resolution. If you have a picture of 300 by 300 pixels, and you scale it to one by one inch, the resolution will be 300 dpi. If you scale it to two by two inches, the resolution will decrease, but the size of the image bytes will remain the same.

**The increase of size of a PDF when you add an image depends on the type of image.**

- If you add a PNG file, iText will decode the PNG into pixels, create a bitmap, and add the compressed bitmap instead of the PNG, because the PDF specification doesn't have native support for PNG.
- If you add a transparent image (e.g. a transparent GIF or PNG), iText will add two images: the opaque image as well as an image mask that defines the transparent parts. Why? Well, that's how transparency is defined in the PDF specification.
- ... (The behavior of all of the different types of images is described in one of my books. If you want to know more, I could look it up, or put it on the official web site if it's not already there somewhere.)
- If you add a JPG, an exact copy of those bytes will be present in the PDF. It will be wrapped inside a stream object, causing some overhead, but no as substantial as a quarter megabyte.

Reading your question, I assume that you are adding a JPEG, but the increase of the file is much higher than you expect. We should take a look at the original PDF and your code to give a conclusive answer. I'll take one guess though. Suppose that the original PDF was compressed using the compression introduced in the PDF 1.5 specification (compressed objects + compressed XRef table), and you don't tell the stamper that you want the final result to use that compression, iText may create a PDF that only uses compression as defined in the PDF specifications prior to PDF 1.5. That cause is totally unrelated to you adding an image, but it could result in a difference of a quarter of a megabyte.

Comment: thanks for your perfect explanation. I have included the code in the edited question, and the image is JPEG.

I use PdfStamper class to sign PDFs like this:

PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(new PdfReader(inputStream), outputStream, '\0');

But I haven't use any options to use that compression. How can I use it? Thanks again

Comment: You are creating a digital signature. This means that you are extending the document with a signed hash of the original document and plenty of other information. Is that your intention? If so, then it shouldn't surprise you that the file size increases: you aren't merely adding an image, you are also adding a signature!

Comment: Yes, @bruno-lowagie, but the size difference remains even with signed PDFs. 3-page signed PDF is 113KB, and the image increases size to 1.42MB. Thanks again.

Comment: @yaki_nuka Some things are still unclear. For instance: you can't add an image to a signed PDF without breaking the signature. Your introduction of the concept of digital signature into this discussion is confusing, and makes it hard (if not impossible) to continue the conversation.

Comment: I understand the signature concept. I have 4 different PDFs: no sign and no image (96KB), sign and no image (113KB), no sign and with image (1.41MB), sign and with image(1.42MB). I haven't tried to modify any existent PDF, signed or not. All four PDFs are generated from raw, and then, 2 of them are signed. I'm comparing PDF file sizes (the four possible combinations exposed before) to try to understand the size difference. Thanks

Comment: OK, so we can rule out the signature as the cause, but since you don't share the image, we can't further investigate. Please note that you probably should be an iText customer, since you probably aren't using iText in an open source context (you can't use iText without purchasing a commercial license in a closed source context). Since you are (or should) be a customer, you can share confidential information (such as the image) under NDA with iText Software.